# Hadoop hdfs namenode failing to format with error java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: windows, hadoop, namenode

Getting below error while running command 'hdfs namenode -format' for installing hadoop on windows 11. Does anyone has solution to this? Have also tried all ways to write folderpath.

```
Re-format filesystem in Storage Directory root= C:\foldername\hadoop\data\dfs\namenode; location= null ? (Y or N) y
2022-01-30 16:15:18,743 INFO namenode.FSImage: Allocated new BlockPoolId: BP-1735035859-192.168.29.208-1643539518728
2022-01-30 16:15:18,743 INFO common.Storage: Will remove files: []
2022-01-30 16:15:18,743 ERROR namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.nio.file.Files.setPosixFilePermissions(Files.java:2044)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage$StorageDirectory.clearDirectory(Storage.java:452)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.format(NNStorage.java:591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.format(NNStorage.java:613)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.format(FSImage.java:188)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:1206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1649)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1759)
2022-01-30 16:15:18,759 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
2022-01-30 16:15:18,759 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at LAPTOP/192.192.192.192
************************************************************/
```

Comment: Seems like you are missing a `chmod` command with `winutils`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are hitting a known issue - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-14890. Its been fixed for some time now, so perhaps try a newer version and see if that works?